# Highcharts how to show certain tooltips and don't show others

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to show tooltips for only the last two series when hovering the mouse over the graph. In this example the idea will be to show only the tool tips for the values 1699 and 1750. The rest of the values can't show any tooltips when hovering the mouse. How can I achive that? I haven't found any way to do so. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

```js
(function () {
var categories= ['1350', '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1699', '1750'];
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
           labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return categories[this.value];
                }
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            split: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                }
            }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="grafica1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `formatter` like this :

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          if(this.points[0].key < (this.points[0].series.xData.length -2)){
                return false;
          }
          var s = [];
          s.push(this.x);
          this.points.forEach(function(point) {
            s.push('<b>' + point.series.name + '</b>: ' + point.y);
          });

          return s;
        },
        split: true
    },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/5enyggxr/2/)

<del>Not the cleanest code (there still an error in the console) but it's work.</del>

**Edit**
Following Deep 3015 comment, code and fiddle updated

Comment: insread of just `return` update with  `return false`, no console error. check http://jsfiddle.net/1htqpc1L/

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap `tooltip.prototype.renderSplit` method to show the tooltip only if the points have certain x values.

```
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Tooltip.prototype, 'renderSplit', function (p, labels, points) {
  if (!this.options.showOnLastTwo) {
    return p.call(this, labels, points)
  }

  const point = points[0]

  if (point) {
    const allowedXs = point.series.xData.slice(-2)

    if (allowedXs.includes(point.x)) {
      return p.call(this, labels, points)
    }
  }

  this.destroy()
})
```

And set in tooltip options `showOnLastTwo` flag to true:

```
tooltip: {
  split: true,
  showOnLastTwo: true
},
```

The flag is not necessary but the wrap changes Highcharts globally so it will affect every chart - the flag will prevent this.

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/sLvekuht/1/